# Anime where they wore gauntlets that could control monsters, and they could combine them with other monsters to create big ones

Tags: story-identification, anime

They wore gauntlets that would pull up a display where they could combine captured monsters into bigger monsters. There were about 7 main characters, five male and two female, five of them about 15-16 and two of them older, coaches for the teams. One was elderly and the other in his late 30s. It's like a tournament: there are teams and that's how they got the gauntlets except for two of them, who got their gauntlets from excavation, like ancient gauntlets. I watched this at home and on YouTube.